# An example of a metric space with a property

Tags: general-topology

Can anyone bring an example of a metric space which has at most countable compact subsets, but it has uncountable closed subsets?!

Answer (score 5):

The natural numbers with the discrete topology has uncountably many closed sets (as  every subset is closed and the power set of the natural numbers is uncountable). On the other hand, only the finite subsets are compact and so there are only countably many compact subsets.